# Multi user authorisation on controller actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

I’m building a small application that will have multiple users using ASP.NET MVC, but I’m not sure how to handle user authorisation in the scenario below. I may be missing something obvious as I’m still learning, so any advice is appreciated.

Basically, to illustrate my problem, consider that I’m building a very small email like messaging system. Here is the action to read a message:

```
/Message/ReadMessage/1
```

Where **Message** is the controller, **ReadMessage** the action and **1** is the MessageId.

Now this message was for “Bob” and in the db his UserId is stored with the message. Another user called “Fred” has also received a message and the MessageId for this is 2.

In my application, there would be no way for Bob to see Fred’s messages on the page directly or through links (messages should be private to each user), so what is the best way for me to protect from Bob simply changing the MessageId in the URL manually from 1 to 2 and viewing Fred's message?

As a current solution to this, I have a very simple check at the beginning of my controller action which compares the UserId stored with the message to the current UserId and if they don’t match, the user is redirected (to say, their inbox).

Is this a suitable solution for such a scenario? I get the feeling that while this works now, it isn’t the best approach to this problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your controller needs to check that the current user is allowed to access the resource ( message in this case )

Comment: I'm currently doing this already, so that's great. Thanks for the answer.